# In the quadrilateral abcd, bd is the bisector of angle d. If c = 30, ad = 2, bc = 4 and cd = 6, then what is the area of ​the quadrilateral abcd?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral, bisection

In the quadrilateral abcd, bd is the bisector of angle d. If c = 30, ad = 2, bc = 4 and cd = 6, then what is the area of ​​the quadrilateral abcd?

Comment: It is conventional in elementary geometry to use upper case for points and lower case for the lengths of sides, so your question is confusing. Then you say $c=30$, do you mean that $\angle C=30^o$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $BK$ be an altitude of $\Delta BDC$ and $BM$ be an altitude of $\Delta ABD$.

Thus, $BM=BK=\frac{4}{2}=2$ and
$$S_{ABCD}=S_{\Delta ABD}+S_{\Delta CBD}=\frac{2\cdot2}{2}+\frac{2\cdot6}{2}=8.$$

Comment: Thank for your answer...can you solve this without sin?

Comment: I fixed. See now.

Comment: @H.franky: If this answer satisfies you, then you should upvote it and "accept" it by clicking the up-arrow and the checkmark on the left. That's how you say "Thank you" on this site.